# Formulario com calculo

Tags: javascript, html

Estou agora a fazer um site de aluguer de equipamentos no entanto falta-me apenas o essencial dele para o acabar, um formulário que permita calcular o custo do aluguer tendo em conta o preço do produto, a quantidade, e os dias que vai ser utilizado, uma coisa do género do usado no [link](http://rental.digitalazul.pt/categoria/objetivas/kit-3-objetivas-xeen-cine-prime-ef/), até agora tenho apenas o calendário em *JavaScript*, que está como mostro em baixo, o resto não estou a conseguir fazer nem por nada.

Código:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 2
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });


function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
    date = null;
  }

  return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>


  <body>
<label for="from">De</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="Data início ">
<label for="to">a</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Data final de aluguer">
</body>
```

Comment: E o que falta fazer ? Está com erro ? Qual a forma de calcular o aluguer? Qual o código que já tentou fazer para esse cálculo? Tente ser o mais especifica possível, para que consiga ter uma resposta ao seu problema.

Comment: Com esse código consigo selecionar a data de inicio e de fim e é apenas o que eu tenho, agora falta calcular o custo de um determinado produto (sendo que pode se alugar mais do que 1 peça, podem ser x gravadores) durante o periodo de tempo que a pessoa selecionar, por exemplo se a pessoa quiser alugar 3 gravadores de 150,00€/por dia  +IVA (450,00€) durante 3 dias sei que terá que dar 1080€ não sei ao certo a relação deste último parâmetro. Falta-me o código que permite fazer este cálculo
Espero que isto seja util.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer o calculo que pretende dentro dos métodos `change` de cada um dos datepickers para que seja calculado cada vez que a pessoa altera uma das datas.

A forma mais direta seria então criar uma função e chama-la em cada um desses sítios:

```
  from = $( "#from" )
    ...
    .on( "change", function() {
      to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
      calcula(); //calcula aqui 
    }),
  to = $( "#to" )
  ...
  .on( "change", function() {
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
    calcula(); //e aqui
  });
```

E essa função de calculo pode calcular os dias subtraindo diretamente a data final pela inicial, o que dá um resultado em milisegundos e converter para dias dividindo pelos fatores corretos. Com os dias que vão de uma data para outra, calcular o valor com base no preço, quantidade e iva, assim:

```
function calcula() {
  //se não tem as duas datas aborta
  if (to.datepicker('getDate') == null || from.datepicker('getDate') == null) return 0;

  //calcular a diferença entre as duas datas em milisegundos
  let diferenca = to.datepicker('getDate') - from.datepicker('getDate');

  diferenca =  diferenca / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24; //converter para dias
  const valor = 150;
  const quantidade = 3;
  const iva = 0.23;

  let total = valor * quantidade * diferenca * (1+iva); //fazer o calculo

  return total;
}
```

Exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy",
      from = $("#from")
      .datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: dateFormat //formatação da data estava em falta
      })
      .on("change", function() {
        to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
        calcula();
      }),
      to = $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: dateFormat //formatação da data estava em falta
      })
      .on("change", function() {
        from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
        calcula();
      });

    function calcula() {
      if (to.datepicker('getDate') == null || from.datepicker('getDate') == null) return 0;

      let diferenca = to.datepicker('getDate') - from.datepicker('getDate');
      diferenca =  diferenca / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24; //para dias
      const valor = 150;
      const quantidade = 3;
      const iva = 0.23;
      
      let total = valor * quantidade * diferenca * (1+iva);

      console.log(`${quantidade} artigos por ${diferenca} dia(s) ficam a ${total}€`);
      return total;
    }

    function getDate(element) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
      } catch (error) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }
  });
</script>


<body>
  <label for="from">De</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="Data início ">
  <label for="to">a</label>
  <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Data final de aluguer">
</body>
```

No exemplo também apliquei a formatação de datas no `datepicker`, que não estava ainda a ser utilizado.

Falta naturalmente contemplar o resto do html que refere a quantidade, preço e esses valores que eu coloquei como fixos para exemplificar, e adquiri-los na função.

Answer (score 0):

Inseri esse código no ficheiro HTML e substitui os parâmetros que achei necessários, no entanto falta alguma coisa porque não me apresenta qualquer resultado
Obrigada

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<script>
 
  $(function() {
    var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy",
      from = $("#from")
      .datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: dateFormat //formatação da data estava em falta
      })
      .on("change", function() {
        to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
        calcula();
      }),
      to = $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: dateFormat //formatação da data estava em falta
      })
      .on("change", function() {
        from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
        calcula();
      });

    function calcula() {
      if (to.datepicker('getDate') == null || from.datepicker('getDate') == null) return 0;

      let diferenca = to.datepicker('getDate') - from.datepicker('getDate');
      diferenca =  diferenca / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24; //para dias
      var valor = $("#valor")
      var quantidade = $("#qtd")
      var iva = 0.23;
      
      let valortotal = valor * quantidade * diferenca * (1+iva);

      console.log(`${quantidade} artigos por ${diferenca} dia(s) ficam a ${total}€`);
      return total;
    }

    function getDate(element) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
      } catch (error) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }
   
  });
 
 
 
</script>

<body>
 
  <label for="from">De</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="Data início ">
  <label for="to">a</label>
  <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Data final de aluguer">
  
   <span class="valor" id="valor"><span>Preço: </span><span class="valor">150.00<span class="euro">&euro;</span></span></span></p>
  
  <span class="valortotal" id="valortotal"><span>Valor Total: </span><span class="valortotal">150.00<span class="euro">&euro;</span></span></span></p>
  
  <label for="quantidade"> Quantidade: </label>
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="qtd" id="qtd" value="1" title="Qtd" class="input-text qtd text"  size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" >
 
 </input>
 </input>
 </input>
 
</body>


</html>
```